# what is the right way to use prefetch_related or select_related to achieve this in django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-orm

hey guys i have these models

```
class Theme(models.Model):
    name = models.charfield()
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.charfield()
class Product(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeginKey(Category)
    theme = models.ForeignKet(Theme)
    ......
class Order(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeigKey(Product)
```

i want to fetch the product and the category of the product from an order instance in one query, i know that for forward foreignkey you should use select related but i don't think there's a way to fetch the product category when you use this:

```
Order.objects.all().select_related('product')
```

so is it right to use this one then:

```
Order.objects.all().prefetch_related('product__category')
```

my last question let's say i have instead these models:

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.charfield()
class Product(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeginKey(Category)
    theme = models.ForeignKet(Theme)
class Course(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeginKey(Category)
    ......
class Order(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeigKey(Product)
```

if i have products and i want to fetch also the category and the courses related to this category too

```
product = LvaProducts.objects.all().select_related('category')[0]
courses = product.category.course_set
```

is this is the most efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Since the relation from `Order` to `Product` is a *many-to-one* relation, and that of `Product` to `Category` is a *many-to-one* relation, you fetch these both through [**`.select_related(…)`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#select-related):

```
Order.objects.select_related('product__category')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can chain relationships in a `select_related` call with double underscores

```
Order.objects.all().select_related('product__category')
```

EDIT: You can run a prefetch on a related model by using the same technique

```
Product.objects.select_related(
    'category'
).prefetch_related(
    'category__course_set'
)
```

Comment: i edited and added another question can you please take a look

Comment: @th3plus please see the edit, you can prefetch a nested relationship using the same technique - `prefetch_related('category__course_set')` in your case

Comment: that's what i am trying to say can we use prefetch_related like this -Product.objects.prefetch_related('category__course_set') even if category is forward foreign key relationship in product?

Comment: i tried to do prefetch_related('category__course_set') i saw that i didn't make any select query or join to the category table when using product.objects.prefetch_related('category__course_set')